# angular directive is undefined in browser console, but defined in nodejs console

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js

I am currently putting together an admin dashboard which displays data retrieved from a db. I am currently having an issue with the attribute `{{pledges}}` displaying in the browser window or  console, and I am seeking a bit of assistance with this. I suspect it is something either very large or very small that I am just not seeing. Here are the following steps I have taken:

1.) attempted to get the retrieved data to display in chrome's console and is returned undefined. I also put in some static data along with the directive to see what is  and is not being loaded. The directive was blank as expected.

2.) made sure the controllers names are spelled correctly and scopes are correct.

3.) performed a console.log on the back-end on `pledge[0].avg_amt_pledge` which displayed accurately.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="box-info">
  <p class="size-h2" ng-controller="pledgeCtrl">{{pledges}}<span class="size-h4"></span></p>
         <p class="text-muted"><span data-i18n="Median Pledges"></span></p></div>
```

**Controller**

```
function(){
    "use strict";

    angular.module("pledgeDisplay", []).controller("pledgeCtrl", ["$scope","$http", function($scope, $http){

    $http.get("javascripts/avg.js")
        .success(function(pledge){
            $scope.pledges = pledge[0].avg_amt_pledge;
        });l

}])}.call(this);
```

**DB query**

```
var query2 = connection.query("SELECT AVG (amt_donate) AS avg_amt_pledge FROM donations WHERE org_id = '3' ",

function (err, rows) {
     if (err) throw err;
     pledge = rows;
    console.log(pledge[0].avg_amt_pledge);
//outputs queried data held in   var avg_amt_pledge.
    });

 });
```

Comment: Initialize `$scope.pledges` outside of `$http.get`. So you will have `$scope.pledges = ""` outside of `$http.get` and inside success callback `$scope.pledges = pledge[0].avg_amt_pledge;`

Comment: Since you know query is valid showing that code isn't as relevant as showing the output for the query to send to client. Curious why api path is a js extension and what output looks like. What do you see when you log response?